# How to stop UserControl inside panel from opening new instance

Tags: vb.net

I have form `formmain`. Inside `panel2` of `formmain` I want to open UserControl named `create_item` using Button `Button2`. The code is:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   
    Dim uc = New create_item
    Panel2.Controls.Add(uc)
    uc.BringToFront()

End Sub
```

Problem is if I click `Button2` two times, two different UserControls open. If `Button2` is clicked and UserControl `create_item` is already open then I want it to show it in front of the other controls. How can I do that? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I see what amounts to this same question over and over again and it shows that people abandon the logic that they have used their whole lives when they begin programming. Let's say that you had a bag and you wanted to only allow one ball in it. If someone asked you to put a ball in the bag, what would you do? You look inside the bag to see whether there was already a ball in it, wouldn't you? That's just common sense. A child would know what to do in that situation. Why is this any different? It doesn't necessarily mean you immediately know the implementation but the logic should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

**Create a `Windows App (.NET Framework)`**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Open the Toolbox**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**

**Add 2 Buttons to Form1** (`ButtonShowUserControl1` and `ButtonShowUserControl2`)

Double-click each button to add the event handler to the form

**Add a Panel to Form1** (name: `Panel2`)

**Create 2 UserControls** (name: `UserControl1` and `UserControl2`) - design as desired.

For testing, one can add a label to each UserControl and set the text property to a unique value such as "This is UserControl 1" or "This is UserControl 2".

**Rename `Form1.vb` to `FrmMain.vb`**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.vb**
- Select **Rename** (name: FrmMain.vb)
- When prompted `You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references to the code element "Form1.vb"`, select **Yes**

Select one of the options below:

**Option 1** (FrmMain.vb)

This option creates an instance of each type of UserControl and adds it to the Panel when the corresponding Button is clicked. To ensure that only 1 instance of each type of UserControl is added, it uses `Find` (which searches based on the name of the UserControl) to check if an instance already exists. Since more than 1 UserControl may exist on the Panel, it uses `BringToFront` to ensure that the desired UserControl is shown.

```
Public Class FrmMain

    Private Function BringDesiredUserControlToFront(ucName As String) As Boolean
        'check if UserControl already exists on the Panel
        If Panel2.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            'find Controls matching the specified name
            Dim ctls As Control() = Panel2.Controls.Find(ucName, False)

            If ctls IsNot Nothing AndAlso ctls.Count > 0 Then
                'there should only be 1 instance of this Control
                Dim ctl As Control = ctls(0)

                'bring UserControl to front
                ctl.BringToFront()
                Return True
            End If
        End If

        Return False
    End Function

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl1.Click

        Debug.WriteLine($"Panel2.Controls.Count: {Panel2.Controls.Count}")

        If Not BringDesiredUserControlToFront("UserControl1") Then

            'create new instance
            Dim uc As UserControl1 = New UserControl1()

            'set property
            uc.Name = "UserControl1"

            'add to Panel
            Panel2.Controls.Add(uc)

            'show
            uc.Show()

            'in case other controls exist, bring this one to front
            'if desired, one can check if other controls exist 
            'and only execute the following statement if other controls exist
            uc.BringToFront()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl2.Click
        Debug.WriteLine($"Panel2.Controls.Count: {Panel2.Controls.Count}")

        If Not BringDesiredUserControlToFront("UserControl2") Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Creating new instance of UserControl2")

            'create new instance
            Dim uc As UserControl2 = New UserControl2()

            'set property
            uc.Name = "UserControl2"

            'add to Panel
            Panel2.Controls.Add(uc)

            'show
            uc.Show()

            'in case other controls exist, bring this one to front
            'if desired, one can check if other controls exist 
            'and only execute the following statement if other controls exist
            uc.BringToFront()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Option 2** (FrmMain.vb)

This option creates an instance of each type of UserControl and adds it to the Panel when the corresponding Button is clicked. To ensure that only 1 instance of each type of UserControl is added, it uses a `For Each` to loop through all of the controls and check if an instance already exists. Since more than 1 UserControl may exist on the Panel, it uses `BringToFront` to ensure that the desired UserControl is shown.

```
Public Class FrmMain

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl1.Click
        Dim uc As UserControl1 = Nothing

        Debug.WriteLine($"Panel2.Controls.Count: {Panel2.Controls.Count}")

        'check if UserControl already exists on the Panel
        If Panel2.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ctl In Panel2.Controls
                If TypeOf (ctl) Is UserControl1 Then
                    'create reference
                    uc = CType(ctl, UserControl1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If uc Is Nothing Then
            'UserControl doesn't exist on Panel

            'create new instance
            uc = New UserControl1()

            'add to Panel
            Panel2.Controls.Add(uc)

            'show
            uc.Show()
        End If

        'show
        uc.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl2.Click
        Dim uc As UserControl2 = Nothing

        Debug.WriteLine($"Panel2.Controls.Count: {Panel2.Controls.Count}")

        'check if UserControl already exists on the Panel
        If Panel2.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ctl In Panel2.Controls
                If TypeOf (ctl) Is UserControl2 Then
                    'create reference
                    uc = CType(ctl, UserControl2)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If uc Is Nothing Then
            'UserControl doesn't exist on Panel

            'create new instance
            uc = New UserControl2()

            'add to Panel
            Panel2.Controls.Add(uc)

            'show
            uc.Show()
        End If

        'show
        uc.BringToFront()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Option 3** (FrmMain.vb)

This option only has 1 UserControl on the Panel at a time. If a UserControl already exists on the Panel, it is removed and disposed prior to adding a different one.

```
Public Class FrmMain

    Private _currentUserControl As UserControl = Nothing

    Private Sub ShowDesiredUserControl(uc As UserControl)

        If _currentUserControl IsNot Nothing Then
            'remove existing UserControl
            Panel2.Controls.Remove(_currentUserControl)

            'dispose
            _currentUserControl.Dispose()
        End If

        'add UserControl to Panel
        Panel2.Controls.Add(uc)

        'set value
        _currentUserControl = uc

        'show
        uc.Show()

        Debug.WriteLine($"Panel2.Controls.Count: {Panel2.Controls.Count}")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl1.Click
        ShowDesiredUserControl(New UserControl1())
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl2.Click
        ShowDesiredUserControl(New UserControl2())
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Option 4** (FrmMain.vb)

This option only has 1 UserControl on the Panel at a time. If a UserControl already exists on the Panel, it is removed and disposed prior to adding a different one. It's similar to Option 3.

```
Public Class FrmMain

    Private _currentUserControl As UserControl = Nothing

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl1.Click
        If _currentUserControl IsNot Nothing Then
            'remove existing UserControl
            Panel2.Controls.Remove(_currentUserControl)

            'dispose
            _currentUserControl.Dispose()
        End If

        'create new instance
        _currentUserControl = New UserControl1()

        'add UserControl to Panel
        Panel2.Controls.Add(_currentUserControl)

        'show
        _currentUserControl.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonShowUserControl2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShowUserControl2.Click
        If _currentUserControl IsNot Nothing Then
            'remove existing UserControl
            Panel2.Controls.Remove(_currentUserControl)

            'dispose
            _currentUserControl.Dispose()
        End If

        'create new instance
        _currentUserControl = New UserControl2() 'create new instance

        'add UserControl to Panel
        Panel2.Controls.Add(_currentUserControl)

        'show
        _currentUserControl.Show() 'show
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Resources**

- [Scope in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope)